# Want to add Color/Image/Icon in Select Option

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, dropdown, html-select

I have Googled and found this functionality is deprecated. Found many solution on Stack overflow but all are showing icon when selected but i need it when dropdown is open and when dropdown is open it's showing Question Mark icon not actual icon.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjS3v.png)
Tried this is on mozilla not like this.
Alternatively If i can bold or change the color of text (DO NOT NEED TO ADD ICON) but it should also on when dropdown is open not after selection. On Mozilla Firefox Color issue is solved it is showing when dropdown is open but not on Chrome or Safari.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout on select2, https://select2.org/dropdown

Allow you to customize your options.

[image]

If you really want to do it without plugin, you can try to use  with custom  to do your own dropdown and make it behave like dropdown with javascript.

Here is the sample code

```js
document.querySelector('#selector').addEventListener("focus",()=>{

            document.querySelector('#dropdownbox').setAttribute("style","");
});

function onclickdropitem(id)
{
    console.log(id);
    document.querySelector('#selector').value = document.querySelector("#"+id+" p").innerHTML;

    document.querySelector('#dropdownbox').setAttribute("style","display:none");
}
```

```css
#selector { width:300px; }
#dropdownbox { position: absolute; width: 300px;}
.dropitem { display: flex; padding:10px;border: 1px solid lightgrey; }
.dropitem img { height:50px; }
.droptext { margin-left: 30px; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <input id="selector" type="text" placeholder="Select your option" />

    <div id="dropdownbox" style="display: none;">
        <div id="test1" class="dropitem" onclick="onclickdropitem(this.id)">
            <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/5279-200.png" />
            <p class="droptext">Testing 1</p>
        </div>

        <div id="test2" class="dropitem" onclick="onclickdropitem(this.id)">
            <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/5279-200.png" />
            <p class="droptext">Testing 2</p>
        </div>

        <div id="test3" class="dropitem" onclick="onclickdropitem(this.id)">
            <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/5279-200.png" />
            <p class="droptext">Testing 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to avoid these things because  it may give me the result but it will be different from other dropdowns used in whole application. i want similar dropdown which are using in whole application just added one functionality in it.

Comment: I did some sample for you not sure it is suitable for your case.

Comment: Thanks Gerard for your efforts but this wouldn't work for me. Thanks again